# Is the following WHERE value correct (SQLite, android)?

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

```
(date('now') > date('date_added','+60 seconds') AND subscribed<2)
```

use that on android (with `update` method) to remove old records from the database. 60 seconds is defined just for testing. `date_added` and `subscribed` are database fields (`subscribed int, date_added datetime`).

Comment: do you have an error when testing ?

Comment: No rows are updated (`update` returns 0), when I expect some records to be updated.

Comment: have you tried `datetime()` instead of `date()`?

Comment: I'm not confident with your `date()` function usage http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date

Comment: @tbruyelle those are the MySQL docs, I was going by the [SQLite docs](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html)

Comment: oups my bad, sorry I mixed up mysql and sqlite

Comment: Ok then did you try to remove the quotes for `date_added` ? As it's a column I think you have to write it without quotes isn't it ?

Comment: @tbruyelle, @dave.c - actually both corrections (removing of quotes for `date_added` and usage of `datetime()`) helped me. Please post it as answer, so I will accept it. And, do I need to use `date()` instead of `datetime()`, if I need to compare dates only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sub>(Posting expanded comment as answer)</sub>

did you try to remove the quotes for `date_added` ? As it's a column I think you have to write 
it without quotes isn't it ?

Answer (score 2):

<sub>(Posting expanded comment as answer)</sub>

Try using `datetime()` instead of `date()`, as [according to the documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) `date()` is equivalent to `strftime('%Y-%m-%d', ...)` and does not have a seconds component, whereas `datetime()` is `strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', ...)`.  If you are just comparing dates then `date()` alone should be OK, but you'll need to test based on your requirements.